# Changing image position also changes page's scroll height

Tags: javascript, html, image, scroll, position

I have an HTML document where I create an image with the class "planetas".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <body>
  <img class="planetas" src="./Marte.png">
  <script src="dinamismo.js"> </script>
  <script> dinamismo("planetas", 700);</script>
</body> </html>
```

I then use the function "dinamismo" on it. Here is that function's code in Javascript.

```
function dinamismo(nombreClass, y) {
    let i = 0;
    function actTiempoReal(nom) {
        const imag = document.getElementsByClassName(nom)[0];
        i += 0.01;

        let posicionY = y + Math.sin(i)*500;
        imag.style.position = 'absolute';
        imag.style.top = posicionY.toString() + 'px';
    }
    setInterval(actTiempoReal, 50, nombreClass);
}
```

This function gets the image's address from its class name and makes it move up and down by adding to its y position every 50ms. However, when the image goes below the page's bottom limit, the page expands to fit it in, and then shrinks again when it comes up. I'd like the page to stay locked at its size while the image moves around outside of it. Is that possible?

I tried locking the page's height with max-height and it didn't work.

Comment: `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @Konrad is there a way to still be able to scroll? Just locking the page height at runtime and then being able to scroll through that.